# Blazor8 Web App - Throw 403 from [Authorized] API Endpoints

Tags: asp.net-core, authentication, routes, blazor

I have a blazor 8 web app (the "new" style). I want to host some API endpoints there also, so have put up a sample minimal API:

```cs
public static class SampleApi
{
    public static void MapSampleApi(this WebApplication app)
    {
        var apiGroup = app.MapGroup("api");
        
        apiGroup.MapGet("hello", HelloWorld);
        apiGroup.MapGet("auth", Auth);
    }

    public static async Task<IResult> HelloWorld()
    {
        return Results.Text("Hello World", "text/plain");
    }

    [Authorize]
    public static async Task<IResult> Auth()
    {
        return Results.Ok("Authenticated!");
    }
}
```

It works... But when accessing `Auth` whilst not authenticated, instead of returning a 403 its returning the html response for the log in page.

I've tried everything I can think of and nothing seems to prevent this behaviour. I thought that the `<Router>` would be where to look, and I made that only give the `<RedirectToLogin />` component when the Uri doesn't contain `/api`... But this didn't work. I even commented out the component altogether, and both the Blazor app and hitting the API endpoint in postman were redirecting to the login page. I can't see anything obvious within program.cs, in either the server or client apps.

How would I go about maintaining the redirect with the blazor app, but when its an API endpoint (all API endpoints will be after `/api/`), go ahead and return a 403.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Router Component doesn't have any relationship with this issue, your request hit the endpoints for api not razor components

Also, it should be 401 unauthenticated for your scenario instead of 403 unauthorized,you could check this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/?view=aspnetcore-8.0#authentication-vs-authorization) for more details

And the behavior of redirecting you to loginpage is usually due to the callback events configured in Cookie Authentication  (Identity is based on CookieAuthentication either),so try configure as below:

```
builder.Services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(op => op.Events.OnRedirectToLogin = async (contxext) =>
    {
        if (contxext.HttpContext.Request.Path.Value.Contains("api"))
        {
            contxext.Response.StatusCode = 401;
        }
        else
        {
            var redirectpath = contxext.RedirectUri;
            contxext.HttpContext.Response.Redirect(redirectpath);
        }
    });
```

When I try with a minimal example with Blazor Individual Account template,it works well now:
[image]

If you want to modify the events for unauthorized,try:

```
op.Events.OnRedirectToAccessDenied=...//your codes here
```

If you are working with another auth scheme,please share your codes related